# Get pointer to overloaded function that would be called

Tags: c++, templates, traits, c++20

Please refer to the following:

```
struct functorOverloaded
{
    void operator()(const int& in_, ...) const {}
    void operator()(short in_) {}
};

// helper to resolve pointer to overloaded function
template <typename C, typename... OverloadArgs>
auto resolve_overload(
    std::invoke_result_t<C, OverloadArgs...> (C::* func)(OverloadArgs..., ...) const
)
{ return func; };


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    using C = const functorOverloaded;

    // works with exact function type
    using myT = decltype(resolve_overload<C, const int&>(&C::operator()));
    // can call with something convertible to const int&
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<C,int>, "!!!");
    // how to get the pointer to the overload that would be called when passed int (or double)?
    // the next line doesn't compile (error C2672: 'resolve_overload': no matching overloaded function found)
    using myT2 = decltype(resolve_overload<C, int>(&C::operator()));
   
    return 0;
}
```

The above code allows retrieving a pointer to a specific overload of a function (`operator()` in this case), [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address). One must know the exact argument type (`const int&`) in this case to get the pointer, even though i can just call the specific overload with a plain `int`, or even `double`. Is it possible to get a pointer to the overload that would be called with the specific argument (assuming the call is resolvable / not ambiguous)?

---

Edit: adding context:

I am writing a [`invocable_traits` library](https://github.com/dcnieho/cpp_mex_helpers/blob/master/invocable_traits.h) for introspecting a callable. E.g., given a Callable, it will tell you the return type, arity and argument types, amongst some other properties. To support functors (including lambdas) with overloaded (or templated) `operator()`, the API of `invocable_traits` allows specifying call arguments to disambiguate which overload is to be used (or to instantiate the template). However, one must know the exact argument type (`const int&` in the example above), simply specifying `int` won't do in that case as there is no function with signature `R operator()(int)`. Ideally, I'd like to allow discovering the signature of the exact overload/instantiation that gets called given the provided input argument types, ideally even taking into account any implicit conversions that are applied. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I don't believe this is possible. The only way to get a pointer from an overloaded (member) function is by explicitly disambiguating such as via a `static_cast` or creating an instance of the exact pointer signature from the overload (as you are in `resolve_overload` for `myT`). I don't see how this would be possible any other way unless we can somehow compute what the exact parameter type is to be able to do this -- though I'm interested to see if anyone else has suggestions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what problem is it that you are trying to solve by doing this? Is this just an interesting challenge, or is it possible this may be an [XY-Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) that could potentially be solved by different means?

Comment: @Human-Compiler The context is some [invocable_traits machinery](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272747/invocable-traits-v4) i am writing. Whats posted at that link works for non-overloaded functions, but i am trying to make it work for overloaded ones as well. Users should be able to ask that since the Callable is invocable with some arguments, whats the exact signature of the call that's made? [This version](https://github.com/dcnieho/cpp_mex_helpers/blob/e4629d07c32f04aa93809e752f239c3362d1dea1/invocable_traits.h) does that, but runs into the posted problem.

Comment: I'm reasonably convinced what you want isn't possible, and -- from reading those links -- I worry that the premise of this goal is conflicting with the whole point of concept-based programming. Generic development like this is meant to not _care_ whether inputs are templates, exact or inexact matches, using default-arguments, etc; all that matters is that the concept of an object (whether pointer or functor) is *invocable*. You'll quickly run into problems computing argument types for template-deduced arguments, or the arity of variadics and functions with default-arguments.

Comment: Too bad. And you are right about the problems you see. Arity does not take into account variadic templates (you'll get the arity of the specific instantiation) or default arguments (these are counted in arity since they're not carried in the function (pointer/ref) type. Passing a functor with templated operator() to `invocable_traits` works fine, just same restriction that you must provide the exact argument signature. In general, `invocable_traits` is meant to work where `std::invoke` works, and it does. Sadly just in the case of overloads its more constrained in its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the function of an overload-set which would be called with the given arguments, unless you *already* know its signature.
And if you know, what's the point?

The problem is that for any given arguments, taking into account implicit conversions, references, cv-qualifiers, `noexcept`, old-style vararg, default arguments, and maybe also literal 0 being a null pointer constant, there are an infinite number of function-signatures which would match. And there is currently no facility for "just" listing all candidates.

Comment: I agree its rather limited usefulness. Given the exact function parameters, you can however still detect whether the operator is marked any combination of const, volatile and noexcept (assuming there are no ambiguities with other operators with different qualifiers), and whether it takes old-style vararg. I could in theory produce some machinery that tries all combinations of const and ref for each specified argument, but those combinatorics explode rapidly and may yield a different answer than the overload picked by the compiler since the first not the best match would be found.

Comment: Ok, i have gone down the permutation road (adding const and ref for each argument, all permutations) trying to find an appropriate overload given a set of provided types. It has the limitations you predicted, but its something https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272935/invocable-traits-v5

Comment: It's weird that C++ has all these complex rules for overload disambiguation, but  absolutely no way to get a pointer to it . I think that's' the crux of the issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475013/create-a-perfect-copy-of-a-function-in-c